# MultiTenant: AbstractRoutingDataSource vs MultiTenantConnectionProvider

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-security, benchmarking, multi-tenant

What is the best approach implements MultiTenant (in my case for separate DATABASE scenario).

- Spring focus on AbstractRoutingDataSource
- Hibernate focus on MultiTenantConnectionProvider and CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver

I had implement AbstractRoutingDataSources using SpringSecurityContext session variable to lookup the tenant identificer, but only because it seems more simple than the Hibernate approach.

I would like to get information about if that option had been right or could be better use the other one.

Comment: This article suggests that 2nd level cache will not behave properly unless hibernate is configured as well: https://rjbtechnology.com/blog/2017-01/discriminator-multitenancy-with-spring-and-hibernate-no-filters/

So, it seems both Spring and Hibernate must be aware of it